Retrieving data from a directory with a repeated key
I have 2 arrays like this:
Array(    [0] => 24    [1] => 24    [2] => NOW    [3] => false    [4] => Boş    [5] => USD    [6] => 42.35    [7] => false    [8] => A2U0MT0XPL9B69    [9] => Boş    [10] => USD    [11] => 0.0    [12] => Boş    [13] => US    [14] => NJ    [15] => new    [16] => true    [17] => Boş    [18] => 1062    [19] => 86.0)

Array(    [0] => minimumHours    [1] => maximumHours    [2] => availabilityType    [3] => IsFulfilledByAmazon    [4] => ListingPrice    [5] => CurrencyCode    [6] => Amount    [7] => IsBuyBoxWinner    [8] => SellerId    [9] => Shipping    [10] => CurrencyCode    [11] => Amount    [12] => ShipsFrom    [13] => Country    [14] => State    [15] => SubCondition    [16] => IsFeaturedMerchant    [17] => SellerFeedbackRating    [18] => FeedbackCount    [19] => SellerPositiveFeedbackRating)

When I try to combine them like this with
print_r(array_combine($array1, $array2)); 

the new array looks like this because of the repeated key.
Array(    [minimumHours] => 24    [maximumHours] => 24    [availabilityType] => NOW    [IsFulfilledByAmazon] => false    [ListingPrice] =>     [CurrencyCode] => USD    [Amount] => 0.0
    [IsBuyBoxWinner] => false    [SellerId] => A2U0MT0XPL9B69    [Shipping] =>     [ShipsFrom] =>     [Country] => US    [State] => NJ    [SubCondition] => new    [IsFeaturedMerchant] => true    [SellerFeedbackRating] =>     [FeedbackCount] => 1062    [SellerPositiveFeedbackRating] => 86.0)

What I want is to add values ​​like _1,2,3 to the repeating keys.
[CurrencyCode] => USD [Amount] => 42.35 [CurrencyCode_1] => USD [Amount_1] => 0.0

Thank you very much in advance.

Please format your sample data in a more readable manner. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting Output it inside <pre>...</pre> on your site first, before you copy&paste it, for proper indentation.

Walk over your key array, while keeping count of how many times you encountered each value already. If the current count is > 1, append the underscore and that number.
$array = ['minimumHours', 'maximumHours', 'availabilityType',
          'IsFulfilledByAmazon', 'ListingPrice', 'CurrencyCode', 'Amount', 
          'IsBuyBoxWinner', 'SellerId', 'Shipping', 'CurrencyCode', 'Amount', 
          'ShipsFrom', 'Country', 'State', 'SubCondition', 'IsFeaturedMerchant',
          'SellerFeedbackRating', 'FeedbackCount', 'SellerPositiveFeedbackRating'];

$valueCount = [];
array_walk($array, function(&$item) use (&$valueCount) {
    $valueCount[$item] = ($valueCount[$item] ?? -1) + 1;
    $item .= $valueCount[$item] ? '_' . $valueCount[$item] : '';
});

print_r($array);

Result:
Array
(
    [0] => minimumHours
    [1] => maximumHours
    [2] => availabilityType
    [3] => IsFulfilledByAmazon
    [4] => ListingPrice
    [5] => CurrencyCode
    [6] => Amount
    [7] => IsBuyBoxWinner
    [8] => SellerId
    [9] => Shipping
    [10] => CurrencyCode_1
    [11] => Amount_1
    [12] => ShipsFrom
    [13] => Country
    [14] => State
    [15] => SubCondition
    [16] => IsFeaturedMerchant
    [17] => SellerFeedbackRating
    [18] => FeedbackCount
    [19] => SellerPositiveFeedbackRating
)

